# Close SplashScreen without GUI

Tags: python

I writed some code in PySide (Python). But this scipt closing my app (GUI) and I want to close only splash screen. How should look this code ?
PS. It's possible to write this in PyQt4 ?

```
    def test(self):
    print('Test')
    label = QLabel("<font color=red size=10<b>" + ' It is me, your TEXT ' + "</b></font>")
    label.setWindowFlags(Qt.SplashScreen | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    label.show()
    QtCor.QTimer.singleShot(10000, app.quit)
```

And this is splash screen: [Example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9qkhpzx2zwol4h/splash1.JPG?dl=0)

Comment: Well, you're using `app.quit` as the action on your timer, so obviously it's going to quit the app... maybe you want `label.hide` instead?

Comment: Yes, it's working. Thanks.
And if it's possible I want to white this code in PyQt4 (i don't want import so many library).
I'm trying without positive result :(